# SQLite OLE DB driver for C++ (MFC)

Tags: c++, mfc, sqlite, oledb, driver

I am looking for OLE DB driver to acces SQLite. Is there any? I need it to use under MFC, not .NET.
I have found this but it is .NET driver: http://CherryCitySoftware.com/ccs/Home/Default.aspx

and this but I have no references to this: http://www.newobjects.com/product.asp?Category=71

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You may try [SQLite ODBC](http://www.ch-werner.de/sqliteodbc/) together with the OLE DB Provider for ODBC.

Comment: Good idea but it is too complex. I will create my own methods.